# Adding two yticklabels to the same plot with different text in both

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot in matplotlib with a custom text displayed in the `yticks` positions at the left side using:

```
axs[0].set_yticks(list_with_tick_positions)
axs[0].set_yticklabels(list_with_text_labels_for_those_ticks)
```

Now, i want to add, at the right side of the plot, another set of tick labels, at the same y positions, but with different text labels.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an adaption of the following [matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/two_scales.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

list_with_tick_positions = [0, 1, 2, 3]
list_with_text_labels_for_those_ticks = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax1.set_ylabel('y axis 1', color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
ax1.set_yticks(list_with_tick_positions)
ax1.set_yticklabels(list_with_text_labels_for_those_ticks)

list_with_text_labels_for_those_ticks = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('y axis 2', color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
ax2.set_yticks(list_with_tick_positions)
ax2.set_yticklabels(list_with_text_labels_for_those_ticks)

fig.tight_layout()  # otherwise the right y-label is slightly clipped
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm, twinx() is what i was missing! Thanks a LOT mate!!